# Python loop back to beginning of list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have this list:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want to recall a set of items from it in this way:

```
z = x[1]

print y = [z, z+6, z+7]
```

> ['a', 'c', 'd']

Of course, when I do this, it tells me it's out of range. I don't understand why it does not work. Can you please help me solving the issue?

Comment: You don't get out of range, you get invalid syntax. Get you a good Python manual book.

Answer (score 0):

You mess up a few things in the code you have shown us. Let's take a closer look at what happens here.

```
z = x[1]
```

In this line of code you assign a value from array `x` at index `1`. In this case it means assigning `'b'` to variable `z` (arrays are indexed starting from `0`).

```
print y = [z, z+6, z+7]
```

Here you have invalid syntax. First of all you can't print to console a result of assigning a value to a variable. Secondly, you cannot store two different types in a single array. In your case

```
[z, z+6, z+7]
```

is equivalent of:

```
['b', 'b'+6, 'b'+7]
```

Python does not understand what you mean by `'b'+6` - this expression is incorrect, because you simply can't add `6` to a String. According to your expected output I guess you are expecting something like this:

```
y = [z, x[6 % len(x)], x[7 % len(x)]]
```

Now let's interpret step by step this code. Firstly let's replace `z` variable with it's actual  value:

```
y = ['b', x[6 % len(x)], x[7 % len(x)]]
```

Then lets replace `len(x)` with actual value:

```
y = ['b', x[6 % 4], x[7 % 4]]
```

Then let's evaluate modulo operation:

```
y = ['b', x[2], x[3]]
```

Lastly, lets replace `x[2]` and `x[3]` with their actual values:

```
y = ['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Of course in this case array `y` starts with `'b'` as a first element. It's because we assigned `x[1]` to `z` variable. To get `'a'` instead we have to do `z = x[0]` of course.

#### Full example:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

z = x[0]

y = [z, x[6 % len(x)], x[7 % len(x)]]

print y
```

#### Output

```
['a', 'c', 'd']
```

Hope it helps you understanding what was wrong with your code.

Comment: Hey Szymon, 
Thanks for you very detailed explanation. I definitely am not good at write clean code jaja.

I guess it still does not answer my issue. Maybe I didn't explain myself fully. I am trying to make a musical script that spits out a certain major chord.

Comment: Hi @JoaquinFraga, please provide more information so we can help you. Try editing your question to provide more details. If you can't do that due to low reputation, please paste it here as e.g. https://gist.github.com/ and I will update your question accordingly